# How to solve WAMP and Skype conflict on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wamp, skype

I have Windows 7 (32-bit) installed on laptop.

I downloaded WAMP server and installed it with it's default options.

However, I noticed that Apache does not work (while MySQL does work!).

I tried to install it via `Apache → Service → Install Service` and got a message saying that port 80 is taken by Skype. I turned off Skype, and then Apache started to work.

How can I avoid this conflict and allow WAMP and Skype to work simultaneously?

Should I configure Apache to work with other port? Where?

Comment: The same is for Windows XP

Comment: @Spec And Windows 8. This issue is OS independent.

Comment: This question is offtopic on stackoverflow because it lacks the relation to programming tools. WAMP is basically a web server for windows. Skype is probably not used for development either. Because the nature of usage for both components is not programming related this question is more suitable for superuser.

Comment: A detail blog: http://goo.gl/JXWqfJ

Comment: I think that, It should be reopened or removing [tag:wamp] from this community or at least closing the majority of its questions.

Comment: As on latest Wamp  server 3.0.6 you can do it like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883201/wampserver-your-port-80-is-actually-used-by-microsoft-httpapi-2-0/43555153#43555153

Comment: If you came here looking for a solution for the new skype i.e. 8.xx, unfortunately they have stopped giving that option

Answer (score 240, accepted):

In Skype:

Go to `Tools → Options → Advanced → Connections` and uncheck the box `use port 80 and 443 as alternative`. This should help.

As Salman Quader said: In the updated skype(8.x), there is no menu option to change the port. This means this answer is no longer valid.

Comment: Is there any side effect in Skype to doing this?

Comment: it is asking me to enter a port number.?

Comment: What port number would you recommend to use instead? I just entered 443, since only 80 was conflicting.

Comment: @skibulk it doesn't really matter as long as it's the only app using it

Comment: In updated skype, there is no menu option. How will updated skype port change?

Comment: This answer is no more valid as the newer skype i.e. 8.xx doesn't no more have the Tools options

Answer (score 24):

Run Wamp services before Skype
Quit Skype >>> Run WAMP >>> Run Skype

Comment: This is my preferred method, so I don't have to change any Skype setting.

Comment: This method works initially. After a restart you'll end up with same problem.
For effective solution you should consider to disable/uncheck "use port 80 and 443 for additional incoming connection" in Skype > Tools > Options > Advanced > Connection

Screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/55wiwp9lj/

Restart of Skype required.

Answer (score 12):

A small update for the new Skype options window. Please follow this:

Go to `Tools → Options → Advanced → Connection` and uncheck the box `use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections`.

Answer (score 9):

I think it is better to change default port of Skype.

Open skype. Go to Tools, Options, Connections, change the port.

Answer (score 7):

Detail blog to fix this issue is : http://goo.gl/JXWqfJ

You can solve this problem by following two ways:
**A)** Start your WAMP befor you login to skype. So that WAMP will take over the the port and there will be no conflict with the port number. And you are able to use Skype as well as WAMP.
But this is not the permanent solution for your problem. Whenever you want to start WAMP you need to signout Skype first and than only you are able to start WAMP. Which is really i don’t like.

**B)** Second option is to change the port of Skype itself, so that it will not conflict with WAMP. Following screen/steps will help you to solve this problem:
1) SignIn to Skype.
2) Got to the Tools -> options
3) Select the “Advanced” -> Connection
4) Unchecked “Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections” checkbox and click save.
5) Now Signout and SignIn again to skype. (this change will take affect only you relogin to skype)
Now every time you start WAMP will not conflict with skype.

Answer (score 5):

I know this posting is old, but I had the same problem, WAMP would not go online (green) while SKYPE was running. I simply closed SKYPE, ran WAMP and then reloaded SKYPE. I have not verified this, but I think SKYPE port corrected to allow for WAMP settings. At least I have not experienced any problems doing it this way

Answer (score 3):

```
Options>Advanced>connections
```

Uncheck the option :

```
Use port 80 and 443 as alternative....
```

Answer (score 2):

1. open skype
2. click tools and go to options
3. click advanced option from left side
4. click connection
5. unchecked (Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connection)