# Succeeded installing but could not start apache 2.4 on my windows 7 system

Tags: apache, service, windows-7, installation

I am attempting to install and run apache 2.4 on my windows 7 system
I went to the apache 2.4 bin directory and ran the following:
Note: I opened the cmd window as administrator.
C:\Apache24\bin>httpd.exe -k install

Its output was as follows:

```
Installing the Apache2.4 service
The Apache2.4 service is successfully installed.
Testing httpd.conf....
Errors reported here must be corrected before the service can be started.
(OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its acces
s permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its acces
s permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open log
```

So it installed apache 2.4 as a service but it could not be started. It seems like the localhost port 80 is being used. Is this what **"[::]:80"** means?

I then stopped both the the apache 2.0 service which I had left running and the mysql service, hoping stopping one of them might free up localhost port 80.

I also run netstat -o to see if port 80 is being used. It was not.

But, I then found that a process was using the above socket it is a process that is listening on the above socket

```
 TCP    [::]:80                User-PC:0              LISTENING       4
```

I then ran tasklist and found out that System is using pid 4. 4 is under the pid column

```
System                           4 Services                   0        544 K
```

Finally, from the failed attempt to start the service 
I got an error which was recorded in windows systems events.

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          2/21/2013 1:58:03 PM
Event ID:      7024
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      User-PC
Description:
The Apache2.4 service terminated with service-specific error Incorrect function.

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">7024</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-02-21T18:58:03.723988900Z" />
    <EventRecordID>87756</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="560" ThreadID="7596" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>User-PC</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">Apache2.4</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">%%1</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

The error from the attempt to start says that beacause of lack of access, make-sock could not bind to sockets which to me looked like localhost port 80. For example,

```
  (OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its acces
    s permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
```

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This actually helped me solve my issue which was a totally different issue by the way, but I was getting the exact same service startup error `The Apache2.4 service terminated with service-specific error Incorrect function.`. This question pointed me to look in the error.log file :)

Comment: Your netstat -o option let me found out which program was binding with port 80 skype was the culprit with my machine. To resolve it I googled "skype apache conflict" and this helped me: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705005/how-to-solve-wamp-and-skype-conflict-on-windows-7[/link]. Hope this would help anyone that has the same issue.

Comment: I found out: When running SKYPE apache cannot be started.

Comment: I agree with Joe's solution. In my case I am using Windows 10 and Apache was working until today (1st May 2017). I changed the "Listen" instruction in httpd.conf in the Apache installation folder. Now I am able to start the Apache web server, which I like to do using the Apache monitor application.
If you have installed Apache on Windows, you should have a nice easy to use shortcut to httpd.conf in the start programs menu, under Apache.

Answer (score 21):

Sorry for the belabored question. To solve my problem I just told apache 2.4 to listen to a different port in httpd.conf. Since System was using pid 4 which was listening on port 80, I did not want to explore this any further.

I put the following into httpd.conf.
Listen 127.0.0.1:122

Comment: PID 4 will be used by IIS World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC) most likely. To free the port go to services in windows and stop IIS.

Answer (score 17):

The most likely culprit is Microsoft Internet Information Server. You can stop the service from the command line on Windows 7/Vista:

net stop was /y

or XP:

net stop iisadmin /y

read this
http://www.sitepoint.com/unblock-port-80-on-windows-run-apache/

Comment: You then have to do this after every boot as IIS will restart on boot.

Comment: To avoid that, go into the services and disable IIS. Note: that's "disable", not "stop". On Windows Server 2012 it's called "World Wide Web Publishing Service".

Comment: this solved my problem, will there be problem for other services if this is stopped ?

Answer (score 8):

I have the same problem too, after upgrading win7 to win10.
then I check services.msc and found "**World Wide Web Publishing Service**" was running automatically by default.
So then I disabled it, and running the Apache service again.

Comment: Thanks ! I don't know how this service got activated, as I had Apache running just fine on Win7, before my PC hangs and had to force a restart !

Comment: Thanks this works for me

for anyone wondering how to disable the service, just double click on the service and change the Startup Type to be "Disabled"

Answer (score 5):

```
Port 80 maybe used by Microsoft HTTPAPI

Try to stop the following service:
  Web Deployment Agent Service
  SQL Server Reporting Service
  SQL Server VSS Writer
```

Comment: thanks - this helped me (recently installed SQL Server express)

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue finally, it was because of some systems like skype and system processes take that port 80, you can make check using netstat -ao for port 80

Kindly find the following steps

1. After installing your Apache HTTP go to the bin folder using cmd
2. Install it as a service using httpd.exe -k install even when you see the error never mind
3. Now make sure the service is installed (even if not started) according to your os
4. Restart the system, then you will find the Apache service will be the first one to take the 80 port,

Congratulations the issue is solved.

Comment: Another solution to stop NT kernel&System process from taking this port
In Windows : 
1-open device manager ->then view ->show hidden devices 
2- select "Non-Plug and play drivers" ->HTTP 
3-open it and from driver ->disable

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was due to an IP address that Apache is listening to. Previously I have set it to 192.168.10.6 and recently Apache service is not running. I noticed that due to My laptop wifi changed recently and new IP is different. After fixing the wifi IP to laptop previous IP, Apache service is running again without any error.

Also if you don't want to change wifi IP then remove/comment that hardcode IP in httpd.conf file to resolve conflict.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using windows os and believe that skype is not the suspect, then you might want to check the task manager and check the "Show processes from all users" and make sure that there is NO entry for httpd.exe. Otherwise, end its process. That solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

So, that is why i do a two (or more) post.

I was having the same problem when starting the service (logs can not be opened).

I thought it was because i was trying to have htdocs inside a VeraCrypt encripted container, absurd since i hace such contained mounted and i use a juntion to not affect paths.

The i read the cause could be low ram: after some tests i get to the next conclusion.

Windows is not sending pages to virtual ram to free enough ram if it is a service, for applications it is doing it, i have more than 200GiB of pagefile ready to be used as virtual ram in a 4GiB 64 Bit windows 10.

My solution:

1. Run a free utility that free ram (512MiB in my test)
2. Inmediatly after start the service, it starts with no errors

Real Cause:

- I was using a virtual machine that uses 1/2 physical free ram (1.5GiB)

Hope this help others.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue, then i tried restarting my system after every change and it worked for me:

1. Uninstall Apache2.4 in cmd prompt (run administrator) with the command:
   `httpd -k uninstall`.
2. Restart the system.
3. open cmd prompt (run administrator) with the command:
   `httpd -k install`.
4. Then `httpd -k install`.

Hope you find useful.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

> and changed Listen to 8080

Comment: If you using wsl ubuntu

Comment: Add the following line to the end of the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file:

Comment: AcceptFilter http none

Answer (score -5):

This may be because of shortage in physical RAM.

Check minimum system requirements in the docs and try to close unnecessary programs if possible.

Comment: Despite the downvotes, shortage in RAM causes such an error, FYI. :)