# After installation, WAMP server is not starting on Windows 10

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

**Downloaded** on: http://www.wampserver.com/en/

WAMPSERVER 64 BITS (X64) 3.0.6

- Wampserver 3.0.6 64 bit x64
- Apache 2.4.23
- PHP 5.6.25/7.0.10
- MySQL 5.7.14
- PhpMyAdmin 4.6.4
- Adminer 4.2.5
- PhpSysInfo 3.2.5

After installation, WAMP server is not starting on Windows 10.

*Following is the error log*:

> State of services:
>
> The service 'wampapache64' is NOT started
>    EXIT error code:1066
>    Help message for error code 1066 is:
>
> The service has returned a service-specific error code.
>
> The service 'wampmysqld64' is started
>
> The service 'wampmariadb64' is started
>
> The service 'dnscache' is started
>
> WampServer (Apache, PHP and MySQL) will not function properly if any service
>
> 'wampapache64'
>
> 'wampmysqld64'
>
> 'wampmariadb64'
>
> 'dnscache'
>
> is not started.

Yes MSVC installed :

[image]

Event log :

> The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>    AH00015: Unable to open logs     .
>
> The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>   AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down     .
>
> The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>    (OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80     .
>
> The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>   (OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80     .
>
> The wampapache64 service terminated with the following service-specific error: 
>   Incorrect function.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Best place is to look at Windows Event viewer for detailed service error. Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416403/apache-wont-start-in-wamp

Comment: Is MSVC installed in the system ?

Comment: @DeepanshSachdeva: Yes, MSVC installed, question is updated with screenshot.

Comment: @endo64 :Event logs updated in question

Comment: It looks like you have a permission issue, apache process doesn't have write permission to its `logs` folder. Or probably your antivirus application blocks it. Please try to disable your antivirus temporarily and/or try to execute apache process as administrator to see if the issue is about permissions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Finally got a solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36034867/221919

I checked with command for the usage of port 80,

> cmd
>
> netstat -ao

*Found culprit*

[image]

*After changing port from 80 to 8080 as*

[image]

It works:

[image]

Comment: Thats probably IIS and its associated stuff. Better solution would be to uninstall IIS if you are not using it, and go back to port 80

Comment: Yes, but I am using IIS too for ASP.Net MVC application.

Answer (score 1):

I tried NUMEROUS things including all on this page, nothing worked. Problem was:
Microsoft iis was running as web server.
Stop that and in most cases, not all, it will work.

I wrote a batch file to see status of iis and stop it.
create a .txt file and put the below code into it and rename it to anything .bat

Run it and choose option 2.
Or you can run as two commands (essence of Option 2 in bigger code) in a CMD window too to stop iis:

```
cd %windir%\system32\
iisreset /stop
```

Restart your WAMP server.

Full code for more options (scroll down in Code Box below as there is more):

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
:MENU
ECHO.
ECHO==================================================================
ECHO.
ECHO   ===============================
ECHO    PRESS 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 to EXIT   
ECHO   ===============================
ECHO.
ECHO 1 - STATUS of iis
ECHO 2 - STOP iis
ECHO 3 - START iis
ECHO 4 - RESTART iis
ECHO 5 - EXIT
ECHO.
SET /P M=Type 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 then press ENTER:
ECHO.
ECHO==================================================================

IF %M%==1 GOTO 1
IF %M%==2 GOTO 2
IF %M%==3 GOTO 3
IF %M%==4 GOTO 4
IF %M%==5 GOTO EOF

:1
cd %windir%\system32\
iisreset  /status
GOTO MENU

:2
cd %windir%\system32\
iisreset /stop
GOTO MENU

:3
cd %windir%\system32\
iisreset /start
GOTO MENU

:4
cd %windir%\system32\
iisreset /restart
GOTO MENU
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try killing the task with the same PID as mentioned in the results from the "nestat -ao" command.
To kill the task open the Command prompt as Administrator,
Command: taskkill /pid  /f

Here the /f is used to force the task to end.
Hope this helps...

You can try restarting the system, if the problem persists...

Answer (score 0):

For n00bs like me who stumble across this page:

You will get a nearly identical message if you add a virtual host with an absolute path containing the windows-default "\" as a separator instead of the linux-friendly "/". So if you copy-pasted the absolute path from windows explorer, this may be what went wrong. Just correcting the vhosts file and restarting all services/refreshing wasn't sufficient in my case, I had to remove the vhost entirely from the vhosts file and re-add using the homepage "add a virtualhost" dialog, then refresh WAMP.

Answer (score 0):

My Apache was not starting after I had done Windows updates.

However, the issue was caused by a missing system file that was not compatible with the version of PHP I was using on WAMP.

The way to check the Apache issue is by going to WAMP/logs and then opening the Apache error log file.

From there, I had to go to the Microsoft store and download the file "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio" and restart.

After that, WAMP went green and was good to go.