# Apache service not starting in wamp server in windows 10

Tags: windows, apache, wampserver

I have installed the WAMP server but i am unable to use the port for the Apache service.

I have already installed all Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio
reference: [From here](https://www.itechtics.com/microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-versions-direct-download-links/)

Answer (score 0):

You may try killing the task with the same PID as mentioned in the results from the "nestat -ao" command.

To kill the task open the Command prompt as Administrator, Command: taskkill /pid /f

Here the /f is used to force the task to end. Hope this helps... You can try restarting the system, if the problem persists...

Although, you may wanna check other solutions, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58128317/10038800)!

Comment: Thank you,i have tried to resolve this  but you  are the one who solved my problem