# How to install WAMP server to properly work

Tags: php, wamp

To my greatest surprise, my experience with PHP development starts with a REAL pain in the...installation.

I have started it with a brand new Windows 10 x64 installation.

I found a page where all the necessary informations are present to setup WAMP server (updated as of 2022-05-07): https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en&prerequis=afficher

Unfortunately, the very much REQUIRED services are not downloadable:

Like this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328

[image]

There are SO questions about how to fix various installation issues...

**Wait...WHAT? One of the largest ecosystem in development does not have a single setup environment?**

After I downloaded the VC installers one by one, *manually*, I get this when starting the server:

[image]

So please verify that this is the proper, 2022 experience of using WAMP for PHP development, I'm in a bit of shock after experiencing .NET programming so far.

Can you suggest some real and working solution?

Comment: Not to be rude but if you gonna install everything manually one by one why even bother with wamp ?

Comment: I intend to do it automatically, _manually_ is the SHOCK part of the experience...

Comment: Usually you just have to download a .exe which install everything as WAMP stand for Windows Apache MySQL PHP... Why did you use aviatechno.net in the first place instead of the real version ?

Comment: I downloaded the WAMP setup. It does not work without the MVC installer but they didn't add it as distributables, and you have to search for each of them...and as you can see, it still is not enough :)

Comment: No you don't... You just happenned to download it from the wrong place

Comment: Can you point me to the right direction? I have downloaded from these 2 places so far: https://www.wampserver.com and https://wampserver.aviatechno.net . Is there a TRUE download site?

Comment: All the million versions of Visual C++ redistributables is a pain. (OP is talking about VC dependencies for installing, not server software.) A common reason for Apache not starting is port 80 already occupied by something. Skype or whatever, cmd > `netstat -ano` to see what's occupying it. Look at Apache error logs to confirm. ... Does this answer your question? [After installation, WAMP server is not starting on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46139605/after-installation-wamp-server-is-not-starting-on-windows-10)

Comment: It's a brand new Windows 10 install, I don't use Skype. I'll check it anyways.

Comment: Look at the bottom of this page [The WAMPServer backup repo](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) There is a link at the bottom containing ALL the required MSVC C/C++ Runtimes for both 32bit and 64bit. PLease install both 32 and 64bit runtimes.

Comment: _One small reminder_ You dont pay anything for WAMPServer. Its incredibly flexible and useful in the right hands. But most of all its all free. So to reduce the workload and the likelyhood of people complaining about things being done without there knowledge, you are expected to install the runtimes (with assistance as mentioned above) yourself

Comment: @Nestor you had the same issue when dowloading from wampserver.com ?

Comment: Yes, I had problems with both installer, they looked identical by the way. Aren't they the same?

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward solution is to use a different package that creates a WAMP stack and just works perfectly after a simple install.

This package is [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html).

> The most obvious characteristic of XAMPP is the ease at which a WAMP webserver stack can be deployed and instantiated. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP)

Comment: Those libraries are used by other software, any program that is compiled with MS C/C++ could and probably is using one or the other of these libraries. Adding them to your system is not dangerous or arduious