# Node.js Unhandled 'error' event when using http.createServer().listen() on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-12.04

Salam (means Hello) :)

I've developed a node.js script on my windows seven machine and it's working fine. but when I run it on my Ubuntu 12.04, the following error shows up and halts my app:

```
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1020:19)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1127:5)
    at Object.start (/httpServer/httpServer.js:9:34)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

and the point that caused error is `.listen(80)` in this line:

```
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(80); 
                             ^
```

I've also tried some other port numbers (like 100, 300, 500,...) instead of `80` and the error was still the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [nodejs app can't run on port 80 even though there's no other process blocking the port.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947356/nodejs-app-cant-run-on-port-80-even-though-theres-no-other-process-blocking-th)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On Ubuntu you can't listen on ports < 1024 without root privileges. Try running node under sudo.

```
sudo node app.js
```

Comment: I don't know whether this would be recommendable on a production system though.

Answer (score 7):

You probably have apache running on port 80, so it's conflicting.

Use another port (NOT within 0-1023), or disable apache.

Cheers

Comment: Yep. Anytime you see that ol' `Error: listen EACCES` you can bet that you're either fighting for permissions or fighting with another app for the port.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have something else running on port 80, so it's conflicting.

Read here to find out what is using port 80 and stop it
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-linux-what-running-on-port-80-command/

1. Usually it means another server like apache is enabled. so stop it.

   sudo service apache2 stop
2. or You have `npm start` already running in another terminal
3. or skype is running. in which case go to settings and change it's port. logout n login

   Go to Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connections and uncheck the box "use port 80 and 443 as alternative".[src](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4705033/406659)
4. or use another port

   http-server -a localhost -p 8000

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to install the latest node packets, maybe directly from Node.js server, maybe compiling it.

Try to set a port which is not reserved to any service, like 3700.

Could be heplful to see some other fragment of code, though.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused if you have something else already listening on that port - you can try changing the port from the typical default 80 to something more like 10014 and see if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to rectify the error by explicitely mentionining the "IP address" along with the port when listening to the server.