# mysql error while starting service from services.msc

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have installed XAMPP server in my C: drive.When i start apache service from control panel it starts successfully but when i start mysql service it freezes and does not start the service. I tried to start the service using `services.msc` it says the following error

> The mysql service failed to start due to the following error: The system cannot find the file specified.

Anu Suggestions or help please i am stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem do you have Skype on your computer try to change the port of Skype to another no or what you can do is install xampp in d drive and it will work cause some application is stopping it to work in c drive .
Hopefully this helps

Comment: if you have skype do u know how to change its port no 80 to another port no

Comment: Go to Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection and uncheck the box "use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections". I think it is better to change default port of Skype. Open skype. Go to Tools, Options, Connections, change the port.

Comment: this is a similar question regarding mysql/apache not starting    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705005/how-to-solve-wamp-and-   skype-conflict-on-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can start it through the XAMPP control panel, I don't think you even need to worry about starting it through services.  With MySQL running (after having started it through XAMPP), open a command prompt, and type this line:

```
mysql -uroot -p -P3306 -h127.0.0.1
```

If it appears to connect to MySQL, you're good.