# WampServer : Your Port 80 is actually used by Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

Tags: apache, web-services, iis, wamp, port80

I've uninstalled my WampServer 2.5 and installed version 3.0
But apache service isn't running and tray icon is orange...
Clicking on test port 80 gave me the following cmd output :

```
***** Test which uses port 80 *****
===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 80 =====
Test for TCP
Your port 80 is used by a processus with PID = 4
The processus of PID 4 is 'System' Session: Services
The service of PID 4 for 'System' is 'N/A'
*** ERROR *** This service IS NOT from Wampserver - Should be: 'wampapache'
Test for TCPv6
Your port 80 is used by a processus with PID = 4
The processus of PID 4 is 'System' Session: Services
The service of PID 4 for 'System' is 'N/A'
*** ERROR *** This service IS NOT from Wampserver - Should be: 'wampapache'
===== Tested by attempting to open a socket on port 80 =====
Your port 80 is actually used by :
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0


Press Enter to exit...
```

**ISS Service has been disabled before and the Activation Windows service process too by the wampserver forum.**

What is the problem then ??

Comment: There are other services associated with IIS that use port 80

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok so that means your system has Microsoft IIS installed or one of the other bits of MS technology that reports that signature, they are doing that on later versions of Windows for some reason.
If you are not intending to use it you can uninstall it, it is not an integral part of windows so its being uninstalled wont effect normal operations of windows,
and if you need to install it again later, it comes as part of the standard OS so you wont need to do anything perticularly clever.

So go to Start -> Control Panel -> Programs and Features
Click the 'Turn windows features on and off' link in the left hand menu.
Wait for the list to load and then find 'Internet Information Services'

Un check the check boxes for the following items ( you may not see all of them ), and there may be others I done know about. You may have all of these or just some of these.

1. IIS
2. Web Deploy 2.0 (Web Deployment Agent Service)
3. MS Sql Server Reporting service.
4. BranchCache ( Windows 8.1 )
5. SQL Server VSS Writer

[List of possible service names](http://blogs.technet.com/b/fort_sql/archive/2010/05/31/list-of-sql-server-service-names.aspx) not sure how up to date this is.

[Tutorial on how to find what ports are in use on your system and what app is using them](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bgroth/archive/2004/11/11/256190.aspx)

Windows will then have a think for a while and then remove those applications, you will probably be asked to reboot to complete the uninstalls.
Reboot anyway when the uninstalls are complete.

Then try wamp again.

#### Alternativeley just disable it/them.

Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services

Find IIS in the list of services.
Left Click that line and select Properties
Change the 'Startup Type' to disabled.
Ditto for the other possibilities if you see them.

Comment: Yeah SQL Server Reporting Service !

Comment: Thank you! It was BranchCache (on Win10)

Answer (score 26):

**Update 2017- Wamp version 3.0.6**

Right click on Wamp--> tool--> apache section-->use a port other than 80

[image]

Now listen to

http://localhost:7080/phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 17):

There is more than one service that could be causing this. Try opening cmd or PowerShell (remember about administrator rights) and run:

```
NET stop HTTP
```

It will stop service that is running on port 80 and will display every service that was disabled to achieve that, simply disable that services for future and that should solve your issue.

Comment: great solution. Remember to run powershell as administrator!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and found out that the culprit was the *BranchCache* (PeerDistSvc) service.

After stopping that, WAMP starts up correctly on port 80.

Answer (score 3):

Watch this Video on Youtube:
https://youtu.be/CMIC1UMONEk

the answer is when you install the SQL MANAGEMENT SERVER OF ANY VERSION

new SET OF SERVICES IS been added

WE HAVE TO STOP THE SERVICE SQL SERVER REPORTING SERVICES MSSQLSERVER

Step 1:
Normal process:

Control Panel.. All Control Panel Items...Administrative Tools

....Select Services

or for fast result

in run Type services.msc

Step 2
select show hidden icons

left click on wamp server icon

apache ....service ...install service

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Hyper-V creates tasks/services on port 80. I still dont know the exact name (and probably wont look out for it), but unnistalling the hyper-v worked just fine for me.
In case anyone else had the same problem, theres another tip.