# WAMP Server - local server - 1 of 2 services running

Tags: wamp

I installed `WAMP` server and ran the applpication. The icon in the taskbar stays orange and says "local server - 1 of 2 services running" . Also, I am able to see the `phpMyAdmin` page in the browser but when I try to login it gives the following error:

```
#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. <br />The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

I have tested port 80 and I got this response:

```
    ***** Test which uses port 80 *****

===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 80 =====


Test for TCP
Your port 80 is used by a processus with PID = 6612
The processus of PID 6612 is 'httpd.exe' Session: Services
The service of PID 6612 for 'httpd.exe' is 'wampapache64'
This service is from Wampserver - It is correct

Test for TCPv6
Your port 80 is used by a processus with PID = 6612
The processus of PID 6612 is 'httpd.exe' Session: Services
The service of PID 6612 for 'httpd.exe' is 'wampapache64'
This service is from Wampserver - It is correct

===== Tested by attempting to open a socket on port 80 =====

Your port 80 is actually used by :

Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Win64) PHP/5.6.19
```

I believe that the above result means that there is no problem with the port. I even tried changing the port and still gives the same status - orange icon.

Note - When a prompt from Windows Firewall was shown after installing WAMP, I didn't give access to both private and public networks, i.e. I unchecked both the options.

Kindly help me to run both the services in the local server.

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like your MYSQL Service `wampmysqld` or `wampmysqld64` is not started. Look in the mysql error log or the Windows Event Viewer for error messages

Comment: This thread helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574332/how-to-change-port-number-for-apache-in-wamp

Answer (score 14):

Click on the WAMP icon in the tray and go to Apache > service Administration and check if the service is installed or if it isn't running . You can even reinstall it by removing and installing it again. Do the same with MySQL  . Go to MySQL > Service Administration and do the same things . In my case Apache service wasn't installed and Installing it did the trick. check the image below.

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1F5k.png)

Comment: If your port is currently in use, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883201/wampserver-your-port-80-is-actually-used-by-microsoft-httpapi-2-0

Comment: Before reinstalling anything, just to be sure Internet Information Services (IIS), the Windows Internet Server, is not running and causing a conflict. Run the command prompt or powershell in administrator mode. Then type "net stop w3svc" without the quotes and press enter. That will stop the Windows World WIde Web Publishing Service. After that try to start all the services again from the WAMP icon.

Answer (score 6):

Most of the answers given on the Internet say to change the port used by Apache but that is not the solution in most of the cases.

Actually, **start the WAMP server->right click on the icon ->  tools -> use a port other than 3306 -> click on this -> set on 3308.**

Hopefully, this will resolve the error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but only Skype was using port 80. I just changed port 80 from Skype and make it use another one. OR you can change port 80 used by Apache. To do this go to WAMP -> Apache -> http.conf and change *Listen 80* with *Listen 81* for eg.

Comment: I changed the port and the service is running, but local host is not found, and phpmyadmin also not found. This is final output  ---   #Listen 12.34.56.78:81
Listen 0.0.0.0:81   ----
Listen [::0]:81

Answer (score 2):

The same with me but in my case I installed mysql after installing wampserver so there was a port conflict between the integrated version and the independent version of mysql for the port 3306, so the problem could resolved either by changing one of ports
If you want to change wampserver's mysql's port go to the taskbar icon right click and the go to tools select: use a port rather than xxxx(3306 in my case)

Answer (score 1):

This thread helped me.

[How to change port number for apache in WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574332/how-to-change-port-number-for-apache-in-wamp)

Thread Details  below

Just go to httpd.conf file, for ex. under WAMP environment its situated at:

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\httpd.conf
```

go to line no. 46 and edit Listen 80 to your requirement for ex.

```
Listen 8383
```

newer versions of WAMP uses these 2 lines:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8383  
Listen [::0]:8383
```

Next go to line no. 171 and edit ServerName localhost:80 to your requirement for ex.

```
ServerName localhost:8383
```

Restart Apache and its done !!

Now, you can access with your URL:

http://localhost:8383 or http://192.168.1.1:8383

Hope it helps to people looking for solution here.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the thread stating to use the tray icon's tool option for `using a port other than 80`.

Answer (score 1):

No need to remove and reinstall **WAMP** or edit Host file or change any port. this problem happens when **Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager** service is running. you need just stop IIS to run wampapache service without any problem.
press **start** then type **iis** and run Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager and in right panel press stop. then click on wamp icon on system tray and choose start all services.
this is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue some time back. Tried all kinds of things and finally found the link below. Basically the issue was:

```
A parameter in your 'my.ini' file (C:\Wamp\bin\mysql\mysql<version>) called 'lower_case_table_names'

If there, comment it out and restart MYSQL again."
```

If I recall, also did a computer restart also just for good measures.

http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,136457

Answer (score 0):

This might be because php is not working because the default port 80 is taken so u need to change the port follow these steps
1. Click the wamp icon from the bottom right corner 
2. Go to Apache->httpd.conf and open this file
3. Search for word Listen in the file and change these two lines
            Listen 0.0.0.0:8018 (u can use any digits instead of 18 )
            Listen [::0]:8018
4. Now search for the word localhost and change this line
            ServerName localhost:8018
5. Restart wamp
6. Go to your default browser and type http://localhost:8080/ this will open the                            wamp menu

Answer (score 0):

It's either your WAMP Apache port is clashing with IIS (if that is installed and running), or MySQL port is clashing with another MySQL install.

Edit your WAMP > Apache > httpd.conf by hovering cursor over Apache inside WAMP tray icon. Change port 80 to an available port like 8181. Restart all services.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, where only 1 service out of 2 was running. But my issue was not a port issue.

I had previously zipped up a bunch of .conf files in the alias directory to share them with a colleague, and I left the .zip file there. This caused an error in Apache as it tried to use the .zip file as an alias.

Once I removed the .zip file from the alias directory, my Apache services were working fine.

Bit of an 'outside the box' answer, but this was my issue with the same symptoms!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not a port problem.
if you had a problem because  msvcr110.dll is missing
so after you setup the library you will get this problem service 1 of 2
so in this case you have to reinstall the wamp server.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar similar issue where the server was not starting up with the following message - ***"local server - 1 of 2 services running"*** , with server icon in Orange color.
With nothing updated in the error logs. Finally was able to track issue through -

**Wamp server icon** -> **Apache** -> **Service Administration 'wampapache64'** -> **install service**
Error message : WAMP - 'Your port 80 is actually used - Error'

Resolution : Change the port number of the wamp server to some other number,for example 5050.

Go to: C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf

In that file change the listen port to 5050.

**#Listen 12.34.56.78:5050**

**Listen 0.0.0.0:5050**

**Listen [::0]:5050**

Save and Restart. Now you can see the server started successfully with green icon.

Following threads helped me to resolve this issue :

[How to change port number for apache in WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574332/how-to-change-port-number-for-apache-in-wamp)

[WAMP - Your port 80 is actually used - Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016388/wamp-your-port-80-is-actually-used-error)

Answer (score 0):

GO to run type Services and enter
check these two services must start[image]