# Wamp not working, Can I close svchost.exe and LPOC.exe permanently?

Tags: wamp, request-queueing

My wamp always stays in yellow rather than green, I've found the cause by command `httpd.exe -e debug` and `netstat -ano`, the result shows the port 80 be occupied by System who's PID is 4.

Then I checked the stat of http service and found there are two request queues without name, then I checked their process ID and found they are **svchost.exe** and **LPOC.exe**

[There is my Windows task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6f0q.png)

I could close the two process to release port 80, but the next day it will bu occupied by the same reason.

So how could I "really" close the two request queues?

wish I express clearly, thanks a lot.

Comment: You probably have IIS and some other unnecessary stuff running, [see this answer for what you need to look for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34896999/2310830)

Comment: Dont attempt to close svhost, it is a service that runs multiple other services that are required by the OS