# WAMP is not starting since skype is used once, even after it is uninstalled

Tags: apache, windows-10, wamp, port, skype

I used WAMP in the past without problem.

I needed to use skype for once, so I did and now the Apache service of WAMP won't start. When I test port 80 using the WAMP tools, I get this message:

```
***** Test which uses port 80 *****

===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 80 =====


Test for TCP
Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol

Test for TCPv6
Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol

===== Tested by attempting to open a socket on port 80 =====

Your port 80 seems not actually used.
Unable to initiate a socket connection
Error number: 10061 -
```

I tried changing the port Skype uses, but this is not possible in the Windows 10 version. I installed Skype Classic and changed the port there, no result. Then changed Apache to port 8080, without result, so I changed it back to 80.

I fully uninstalled both Skype and Skype classic, then I uninstalled WAMP and installed it fresh again. Even after the removal of Skype and resinstallation of WAMP I still get the same error message.

I also tried to kill the tasks using port 80, but the only task I can actually kill is my firefox browser, result of netstat below.

```
C:\Windows\system32>netstat -aon | findstr :80
  TCP    192.168.178.27:49893   93.184.220.29:80       ESTABLISHED     13120
  TCP    192.168.178.27:49917   216.58.211.99:80       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.178.27:49918   23.208.79.207:80       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.178.27:49919   88.221.254.211:80      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.178.27:49926   52.85.249.5:80         TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.178.27:49931   23.208.77.171:80       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.178.27:49939   23.208.77.171:80       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.178.27:49953   216.58.211.99:80       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.178.27:49960   216.58.211.99:80       TIME_WAIT       0
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705005/how-to-solve-wamp-and-skype-conflict-on-windows-7) question for a similar problem on Windows 7, also it's closed for being off-topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve WAMP and Skype conflict on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705005/how-to-solve-wamp-and-skype-conflict-on-windows-7)

Comment: I tried changing the port Skype uses, but this is not possible in the Windows 10 version, so it's not a duplicate of how to fix this in Windows 7.
Btw, I solved the problem by reinstalling Windows....